# Como eu posso adicionar 2 botões com submenu no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Gostaria de adicionar de forma dinâmica opções ao menu da minha tela no Android, eu vi diversos exemplos, mas todos voltados para um unico botão.

supondo que eu tenha.

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menu.clear()

       val menu1 = menu
                .add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, null)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_round_white)
               .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)

        val menu2 = menu
                .add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, null)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_edit_white)
                .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM) 

}
```

nesse exemplo eu consigo gerar 2 botões ao barra superior da minha tela, a dúvida é como incrementar opções dentro desses botões?

eu utilizo kotlin, mas java ja resolveria.

Comment: Não é melhor você criar o layout no `menu.xml` e sobrescrever o método `onPrepareOptionsMenu` mudando apenas a visibilidade dos itens que deseja que apareça?

Comment: Não, porque as opções são baseadas no que a API me fornece, que podem mudar dinamicamente ;(

Answer (score 1):

É possível de ser feito sim. Tanto por XML quanto programaticamente.

Recomendo dar uma olhada a fundo na documentação do Android sobre menus: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus?hl=pt-br

Para criar os submenus você terá que assosiar estes teus dois `MenuItem` como sumbenus e adicionar novos itens a eles:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
    menu.clear()

   val menuItem1 = menu
            .add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, null)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_round_white)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)

   val subMenu1 = menu.addSubmenu(
                  groupid = 1,
                  itemId = menuItem1.itemId,
                  order = 1,
                  title = "Título")

   val subItem1 = subMenu1
            .add(Menu.NONE, 11, Menu.NONE, null)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_round_white)
            .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)

}
```

PS: Nomeei os parâmetros na função `addSubmenu` para ilustrar os parâmetros, não é necessário tê-los assim.

Aí você repete com os outros itens. Entretante recomendo fortemente fazer isso usando menus em XML e inflar da acordo com a necessidade. Pois é muito mais fácil dar manutenção nesse tipo de código pois a construção fica muito mais simples e dividida em camadas.

Comment: Eu entendi o seu exemplo, mas nesse caso como eu poderia também acrescentar um menu de opções ao primeiro botão, nessa parte que boio. Precisa ser programaticamente pois as opções vem fornecidas pela API, baseado no acesso, resumindo são 2 botões na action bar e esses 2 botões possuem varias opções.